# How to include a video in my apps intro?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating an iphone app using cocos2d and I was wondering if it would be possible to play a video as an intro of the scene and if its possible how would I do that and what video format should I use?

**Just additional info on what I mean**

I am looking to include a small animation like Cut the rope has, a small animation before a scene is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Add MediaPlayer framework to your project.

Add this header file

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

 NSURL *urlString = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SAP_Business_Analytics_new_audio_low" ofType:@"mov"]]; 
player  = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:urlString];
[[player view] setFrame: [self.view frame]];  // frame must match parent view
[self.view addSubview: [player view]];
[player play];
```